# How to get the complete path of the file being uploaded?

Tags: php, upload

I want to check the type of image being uploaded. I wrote the following snippet for this.

```
if(exif_imagetype($_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    echo "This is a JPEG image";
}else if(exif_imagetype($_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    echo "This is a png image";
}else { echo "else statement"; }
```

but `$_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']` doesn't return the complete path of the image on the client's computer. Thus I am unable to check the type of image.

Comment: No it doesn't return the full path from the client computer; but this shouldn't be nececessary because you're not checking the file on the clients computer but the file they've uploaded to your server

Comment: Why are using that..Why dont you simply explode the filename using "." and check the extension of the file.?

Comment: The “type” of a file has nothing to do with under what path it may be stored anyway. And as @Mark already said, you don’t get the local path of an uploaded file in current browsers, because that’s a security matter – what paths I use in my file system locally is not the business of any website, even if I upload a file to it willingly. (In IE you can still set it up in the Internet Options that the path shall be send as well, but that’s not the default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name']`. `exif_imagetype()` reads first few bytes of a image file, hence it needs to know the path to the image file, which is stored in the `tmp_name` field.

Comment: but `tmp_name` gives the path on the server

Comment: Of course it does, that's the only way PHP can access that file. It has to be uploaded first in order to be checked by `exif_imagetype`

Comment: okay..so I should check like `if($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'].exif_imagetype($_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG`) ?

Comment: I think you are confusing PHP with some other language. Use the code that you originally asked about, but instead of `['name']` use `['tmp_name']`.

Comment: Okay. When is the image uploaded ? I mean I don't see any code that is uploading or parsing the file. Instead `$_FILE[][]` already contains the uploaded file.

Comment: That's also correct. It is handled entirely by PHP. It uploads the file to a temporary location (hence the field `tmp_name`). Basically when a file is available in the `$_FILES` global variable, it has already been uploaded to the server. You should check out this page of PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php